# Can visual studio 2019 connect to a git repository NOT in azure devops

Tags: git, visual-studio

In visual studio 2019 team explorer, click Manage Connections, connect to a project, it only show hosted repositories for a microsoft account, and "Add Azure DevOps Server" option, so it does not allowed for connect to git repositories not in azure devops server? using non Microsoft Account?

[image]

Comment: do u add your email id in Azure DevOps Server?

Comment: I mean can visual studio allow to connect to git repositories NOT in Azure DevOps Server, NOT using Microsoft Account...

Comment: you must be use microsoft account for connect Azure Server.

Comment: I mean NON azure devops server, e.g. If I have a Gitea self-hosted Git server, can I use visual studio to connect?

Comment: yes you can connect to git and sorry misunderstanding your previous question.

Comment: but how? as the screen dump shown, when conect to a Project, it only ask for Microsoft Account and project in Azure DevOps Server...

Comment: please check link :- [here](https://yourbrainoncomputers.com/using-git-with-visual-studio-2019-the-ultimate-guide/)

Comment: do you mean the part "https://yourbrainoncomputers.com/using-git-with-visual-studio-2019-the-ultimate-guide/#Set_Up_Remote_Repositories"? in visual studio 2019, no this screen....